# MissingMethodException PostAsJsonAsync exception

Tags: c#, .net, vsix

I installed my vsix project in a system in VS 2015 professional and during execution, I am getting the below exception in a method where I used `PostAsJsonAsync()`.

**Error:**

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, System.String, !!0)'.       
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
```

I have `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting` (`System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension nuget pkg`) dll in vsix project.
I am getting this exception only in VS 2015 and not in VS 2017.

And I dont get this exception when I install the vsix in my system's VS 2013.
Am I missing something?

Comment: All VS releases are on the same machine?

Comment: No. Only VS 2015 is installed in that machine where I am getting this exception. In my machine I have both VS 2015 and 2017

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any resolution to this?